# Run latexmk inside z shell instead of shell

Tags: latex, auctex, shell, bibtex, zsh

## Problem

I am using `latexkm` to compile `.tex` documents, and recently I got this error while compiling:

```
Running `latexmk' on `AF2021_serie5' with ``latexmk -bibtex-cond -pdf -synctex=1 AF2021_serie5''
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 17 Apr. 2020, version: 4.69a.
Latexmk: applying rule 'biber AF2021_serie5'...
Rule 'biber AF2021_serie5': The following rules & subrules became out-of-date:
      'biber AF2021_serie5'
------------
Run number 1 of rule 'biber AF2021_serie5'
------------
------------
Running 'biber  "AF2021_serie5"'
------------
sh: biber : commande introuvable
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  biber AF2021_serie5: Could not open biber log file for 'AF2021_serie5'
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.

TeX Output exited abnormally with code 12 at Tue Oct  6 21:15:40
```

I am apparently not the only one to have had this problem [(1)](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7313) but the solution in the link did not fix it for me.

## Solutions tried that do not fix the problem

I figured that

1. I am using `zsh` as my default shell when I open a terminal, while emacs seems to load `sh`.
2. Compiling the `.tex` files with `latexmk` from the terminal does not generate this error.
3. Launching emacs with `SHELL=/bin/zsh emacs` and then using `C-c C-c latexmk`does not generate this error.
4. Adding

```lisp
(setq-default shell-file-name "/bin/zsh")
(setq-default explicit-shell-file-name "/bin/zsh")
```

to my `.emacs` does not fix the problem; however when I click on `Run Shell Interactively`, I can compile the `.tex`with `latexmk` and it does not generate this error.

5. Adding

```lisp
(setq tex-shell-file-name "/bin/zsh")
(setq TeX-shell "/bin/zsh")
```

to my `.emacs` does not fix the error. It still seems that latexmk is ran through `/bin/sh`.

## Additional information

### Part of my `.emacs`:

```lisp
;; == AucTeX == ;;
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq preview-auto-cache-preamble t) ; stop preview pestering
; (setq-default TeX-master nil)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode) ; Word wrapping
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'LaTeX-math-mode)
(setq LaTeX-electric-left-right-brace t) ; Automatic close parenthesis
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t) ; Compile as a PDF
(setq reftex-ref-macro-prompt nil) ; Disable annoying reference prompt screen

;; == RefTeX == ;;
(setq reftex-bibliography-commands '("bibliography" "nobibliography" "addbibresource"))

;; === LatexMK - automatically recompile and run bibtex ===;;
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (push
    '("latexmk" "latexmk -bibtex-cond -pdf -synctex=1 %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
      :help "Run latexmk on file")
    TeX-command-list)))
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook '(lambda () (setq TeX-command-default "latexmk")))
```

### result of `which biber` (from `zsh`)

`/usr/bin/vendor_perl/biber`

### result of `which biber` (from `sh`)

`/usr/bin/vendor_perl/biber`

## Final question, I guess

What can I add to my `.emacs` so that `latexmk` is ran inside of `zsh` instead of `sh`?

Comment: What happens if you run `latexmk` in a terminal that is running `sh`?

Comment: It actually works, I don't have any error.

Comment: Then it has to be `exec-path` that's wrong: what is its value?

Comment: @NickD Using `M-x describe-variable exec-path`, it returns `exec-path is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is
("/usr/bin/vendor_perl" "/usr/local/bin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/usr/bin" "/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin" "/usr/lib/emacs/27.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu")
Original value was 
("/usr/local/bin" "/usr/local/sbin" "/usr/bin" "/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin" "/usr/lib/emacs/27.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu")`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has anything to do with `zsh` vs `sh`. I believe it has to do with subprocessess of emacs not having the path required to find the `biber` executable, whereas interactive shells apparently do.

Try adding the path to `exec-path`: evaluate the following form

```el
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/usr/bin/vendor_perl")
```

and try your `latexmk` run. If that works, add the line to your init file, restart emacs and test again.

EDIT: The doc string for `exec-path` says:

> List of directories to search programs to run in subprocesses.
> Each element is a string (directory name) or nil (try default directory).

so it should resolve the `sh: biber : commande introuvable` done in the subshell, particularly since you say that in an interactive `sh`, doing `which biber` finds the executable. Not sure why you are still having problems.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. Adding `(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/bin/vendor_perl/")`does not fix it either. I still get the same weird error that it is `sh` that tries to run biber?? I don't have a `.latexmkrc` file. Could the error come from this?

Comment: I thought thererror was this: "sh: biber : commande introuvable"

Comment: Do not add it to `load-path` unless you have lisp libraries in there (which you should not have).